# How to compare the values with other nodes values in XSLT and output the unique values

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following xml file. And I need to remove the end date of the each node if the end date is the start date of another node.

```
    <time_Off_Event_group>
        <StartDate>20211206</StartDate>
        <EndDate>20211207</EndDate>
    </time_Off_Event_group>
    <time_Off_Event_group>
        <StartDate>20211209</StartDate>
        <EndDate>20211210</EndDate>
    </time_Off_Event_group>
    <time_Off_Event_group>
        <StartDate>20211210</StartDate>
        <EndDate>20211211</EndDate>
    </time_Off_Event_group>
```

The expect xml information should be like this. Can this be done be the xlst?

```
    <time_Off_Event_group>
        <StartDate>20211206</StartDate>
        <EndDate>20211207</EndDate>
    </time_Off_Event_group>
    <time_Off_Event_group>
        <StartDate>20211209</StartDate>
        <EndDate>20211211</EndDate>
    </time_Off_Event_group>
```

Comment: Your description "I need to remove the end date of the each node if the end date is the start date of another node." doesn't seem to match the expected result as there not only the `EndDate` of a `time_Off_Event_group` has been removed but the whole `time_Off_Event_group` has been deleted. And, yes, sure, it can be done in XSLT, but you are supposed to give it a try and show us that attempt and any problems you run into, errors you get or wrong result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Judging from your example, you are actually trying to merge adjacent nodes if the end date of the first one is the same as the start date of the second. Presumably there can be more than two such nodes in a group.

If that's a correct interpretation, I would use

```
<xsl:for-each-group select="time_Off_Event_group"
  group-starting-with="*[not(StartDate = preceding-sibling::*[1]/EndDate)]">
  <time_Off_Event_group>
    <StartDate>
      <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[1]/StartDate"/>
    </StartDate>
    <EndDate>
      <xsl:value-of select="current-group()[last()]/EndDate"/>
    </EndDate>
  </time_Off_Event_group>
</xsl:for-each-group>
```

But you haven't specified your requirement very clearly so this may be a wild guess.

Comment: Hi Michael, you are amazing! Yes, your assumption is what I want. I was so stupid that I even didn't come up with the for-each group function here. That's why I got stuck on how to process the data.   Much appreciate your answer on this. Really help.

Comment: Please click on the (check|tick) symbol to mark the answer as accepted.